# DynamoDB query/scan only returns subset of items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I noticed that DynamoDB query/scan only returns documents that contain a subset of the document, just the key columns it appears.

This means I need to do a separate Batch_Get to get the actual documents referenced by those keys.

I am not using a projection expression, and according to the documentation this means the whole item should be returned.[1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

How do I get query to return the entire document so I don't have to do a separate batch get?

One example bit of code that shows this is below. It prints out found documents, yet they contain only the primary key, the secondary key, and the sort key.

```
t1 = db.Table(tname)

q = { 
    'IndexName': 'mysGSI',
    'KeyConditionExpression': "secKey= :val1 AND " \
                              "begins_with(sortKey,:status)",
    'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
        ":val1": 'XXX',
        ":status": 'active-',
    }
}
res = t1.query(**q)

for doc in res['Items']:
    print(json.dumps(doc))
```

Comment: No, this is not right. A simple awscli query to a DynamoDB table will show you all the attributes of the requested item. Can we see some code?

Comment: @jarmod I added some code I used to test this. Other programs show the same behavior though.

Comment: You have KEYS_ONLY for the projection type for the GSI?

Comment: @jarmod I believe so yes, but that  doesn't stop batch_get_items returning the whole doc.

Comment: BatchGetItem doesn't use an index so it's not limited to the projected attributes of any given index.

Comment: @jarmod if that is the case the documentation is misleading and false then, as clearly scan/query don't return the whole document, just what has been projected. I have quite large documents and I would rather not store them twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193665/discussion-between-jarmod-and-aaa90210).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation is discussed in the documentation for the [Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-Select) parameter. You have to read quite a lot to find this, which is not ideal.

> If you query or scan a global secondary index, you can only request
>   attributes that are projected into the index. Global secondary index
>   queries cannot fetch attributes from the parent table.

Basically:

- If you query the parent table then you get all attributes by default.
- If you query an LSI then you get all attributes by default - they're retrieved from the projection in the LSI if all attributes are projected into the index (so that costs nothing extra) or from the base table otherwise (which will cost you more reads).
- If you query or scan a GSI, you can only request attributes that are projected into the index. GSI queries cannot fetch attributes from the parent table.